# date calculations using unix time

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

Looking for help in unix to get the following date stamps using unix date:

```
today at 12:00am  
12:00am - 15 days ago
12:00am - 30 days ago
```

in Unix epoch time? (`1300295838`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today at 12:

```
mydate="`date +%D` 12:00"
```

To do date arithmetic:

`date -d "$mydate 15 days ago"`

To get epoch time:

`date +%s`

To put together in oneliner:

```
date -d "`date +%D` 12:00 15 days ago" +%s
```

Comment: can you do this in one string?

Comment: just playing with the string, but is `days ago` key words? If i remove them, answer is invalid.

Comment: yes, it is. i found some other examples on the net. ok. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

to calculate the date for YESTERDAY:

time is the current time in seconds(the number of seconds in a day)

```
dateYYYYMMDD=`perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime(time-60*60*24);'`
```

time +/- calculate the seconds for your desired date after or before the current time in seconds.

Comment: I should note that you can use this on Solaris (system v) system because for whatever reason they don't support the BSD date formatting like what is defined in the above answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date -d` on the shell to have it display the time you specify, not the current time. For time formatting characters, see: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date

Answer (score 0):

You can use a perl library such as [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) to do this quite easily.

For example, the following code creates a new date my subtracting 15 days from today and then calls the epoch function:

```
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now
                 ->subtract(days => 15)
                 ->set_hour(0)
                 ->set_minute(0)
                 ->set_second(0);

print $dt->epoch(),"\n";
```